# Sending files between two raspberry pi using serial port

Tags: python, file, serial-port, file-transfer

In our project we want to exchange every type of file (csv,txt,pdf,xlsx,...) between two raspberry pi using the serial port.
For example: We want to send a .pdf file from the first raspberry pi to the second raspberry pi.
We want to develop this in Python.

Has anyone a good starting point for developing this?

Regards,
Michael

Comment: A quick search for "raspberry pi python serial port" has plenty of guides.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't an implementation of Kermit for Python.  The official recommendation from kermit.org discourages such ports, suggesting you shell out to their binary when necessary.